# long polling php foreach loop data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if its possible or how can I get ajax to update data from php foreach outputted data using long polling. So far my code is set up like the following.

```
<?php
    if ( $posts ) {

        foreach ( $posts as $post) :

        $postid = $posts['id'];
        $request_posts_comments = regular_query(
        "SELECT a.from_who, 
                a.dateposted, 
                a.topostid, 
                a.commenttext, 
                b.firstn, 
                b.lastn,
                c.defaultphoto
         FROM comments a
         INNER JOIN users b 
         INNER JOIN userprofiles c
         ON a.from_who = b.id
         AND b.id = c.user_id
         WHERE a.topostid = :postid", ["postid" => $post_idr], $conn);
?>
             <div class="divwrap">
                 <div class='posttext'><?php echo $post['posttext']; ?></div>
                 <div class='postcomments'>
                    <?php  
                        foreach ( $request_post_comments as $comments) :
                    ?>
                 <div class="commentdiv"><?php echo $comments['text']; ?></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </div>

             </div>
<?php

        endforeach; }
?>
```

What I want is: When someone updates a post and say my friend checks out the posts page and he's reading the comments then i post a comment from somewhere else, I want the comments to appear without him reloading the page. So if any posts containing comments I want them to fade in without reloading the webpage only when there are new comments to a post ... so i hope this question makes sense ...

Comment: long polling doesn't seem to be compatible with PHP. If you can't replace PHP with another technology on the server you'll probably have to resort to polling at intervals.

Comment: You don't want to keep the script running, you just want to call it over and over again. Have your JavaScript make a request for new posts ever n seconds, and the PHP script will just return the new comments if there are any. That's how most things work, like the "questions with new activity" here, for example.

Comment: What you can do is replace the comments section using ajax which will be executed every x mins with thw help of setInterval in javascript

Comment: @Kapilgopinath can you post an example as an answer please

Comment: You can do long polling with PHP. But with long polling in common, you can only send 1 request, and then wait for x responses. When understanding your question, you want to send several requests? I don't see any http request code in your question ...

Comment: @dystroy Why shouldn't PHP be able to handle long polling connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() { // paste this to the script tag

                function doPoll() {
                    var arr = [];
                     $('.divwrap').each(function() {
                        arr.push($(this).attr('id').replace(/[a-z_]+/, ''));
                    });
                    console.log(arr);
                    $.post('test2.php',{data:arr.toString()},function(response) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(response);
                        var count = Object.keys(data).length
                        if(count){  // process results here
                            $.each(data,function(id,obj){
                                var id = "#post_"+id;
                                $.each(obj.comments,function(i,cmnt){
                                    $(id).find('.postcomments').append('<div class="commentdiv">'+cmnt+'</div>')
                                })
                            });
                        }
                        setTimeout(doPoll, 5000);
                    });
                }
                doPoll();
            });
```

// now on the body the usual php script that shows the post on page load

```
<body>
        <?php
        $posts = array(array('id' => 1, 'posttext' => 'test1', 'comments' => array('text' => 'comment1')),
            array('id' => 2, 'posttext' => 'test2', 'comments' => array('text' => 'comment2')),
            array('id' => 3, 'posttext' => 'test3', 'comments' => array('text' => 'comment3')));
        if ($posts) {
            $str = 'lll';
            foreach ($posts as $post) :

                $postid = $post['id'];
                $postArr[] = $postid;
                $request_post_comments = $post['comments'];

                //$request_posts_comments = regular_query(
                // "SELECT a.from_who, a.dateposted, a.topostid, a.commenttext,b.firstn,b.lastn,c.defaultphoto FROM comments aINNER JOIN users b 
                //INNER JOIN userprofiles c ON a.from_who = b.id AND b.id = c.user_id WHERE a.topostid = :postid", ["postid" => $post_idr], $conn);
                ?>
                <div class="divwrap" id="post_<?php echo $postid ?>">
                    <div class='posttext'><?php echo $post['posttext']; ?></div>
                    <div class='postcomments'>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($request_post_comments as $comment) :
                            ?>
                            <div class="commentdiv"><?php echo $comment; ?></div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <?php
            endforeach;
        }
        ?>

    </body>
```

// and the test2.php you will have to define your logic to fetch post comments based on the post ids we pass

```
<?php
 $posts = explode(',',$_POST['data']);
 if(1){ // here check in a loop any new comments for the post ids thth we pass
     $posts = array('1'=>array('comments'=>array("New comment1","New comment2")),'3'=>array('comments'=>array("New comment4","New comment5")));
     echo json_encode($posts);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

on page load you will show all the comments using php. Later the comment section will be refreshed using ajax every n secs.

```
(function poll() { // will execute immediately the first time it is called before honouring the wait/timeout interval.
    $.ajax({
        url: "/server/page.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.comments').html(data); // replacing the comments section with the data returned from server
        },        
        complete: setTimeout(function() {poll()}, 5000), // calling poll function again
        timeout: 2000
    })
})();


       <div class="comments"> // this is the area where comments will be populated using ajax

        </div>
```

Comment: I get what you are saying but this wouldn't work the reason i say that is because there will be 10 posts plus with each posts having their own comments and if i make it to update the comments how would ajax know which posts comments to loook for, do you get me?

Comment: We have solution for that. You pass the post-id along with its comments id. Now in the server if  any new comments posted then it will be returned. Now on the ajax success call back we will check the comments against the corresponding postid and append it. Postid can be used in some div so that comments can be appended to it

Comment: I will post you an example soon.